# Attach draggable div to another div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)/[droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) plugins.

I have draggable `div` that I drag onto target `div`. Target `div` is also draggable. I can't seem to be able to figure out a way to attached `div`s to their target to move them together when I drag target `div`.

Any pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to be able to drag div A into div B and then you want to be able to drag div B somewhere as well (with div A still inside it)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here's my code that I was attempting it with: http://jsfiddle.net/wfG3L/4/

Comment: Have you tried using a 'handle' to drag div B?

Comment: Just looked at your jsfiddle and you seem to only drop div A (the card) on top of div B (the stack) but you then don't do anything with it. i.e. div A is not really inside div B…

Comment: Yes, I don't have a clue how to get it inside. Looked at the documentation of the plugin but were not able to find anything that would help me with it. How do I drop it inside the stack div? And would I be able to drag it from that stack to another stack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/wfG3L/5/

If you want to add the draggable div, you can just use $(ui.draggable) directly and append it to the target div, that way you don't have to specify the dropped divs in the .stackDrop to be draggable.